# C++ error: Too many initializers for 'char[26]'

Tags: c++

When compiling, I get the following error:

```
Error: Too many initializers for 'char[26]'.
```

I keep getting this error, can you help me with that? Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int defunct();

int defunct(char a[], char b[], char c[]){
    int d,l,s,m,mod;
    mod = 47;
    s = 1;
    m = 0;
    for(d = 0;d <= 6;d++){
        for(l=0;l<=25;l++){
            if (a[d] = c[l]){
                s *= l + 1;
            }
            if (a[d] = ' '){
                s *= l + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    for(d = 0;d <= 6;d++){
        for(l=0;l<=25;l++){
            if (b[d] = c[l]){
                m *= l + 1;
            }
            if (b[d] = ' '){
                m *= l + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if ((s%mod)==(m%mod)){
        cout << "GO\n";
    }
    if ((s%mod)!=(m%mod)){
        cout << "STAY\n";
    }
}

int main(){
        int i;
        char a[6], b[6];
        char alphabet[26] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};
        i = 0;
        ofstream fout ("ride.out");
        ifstream fin ("ride.in");
        fin >> a >> b;
        fout << defunct(a, b, alphabet);
        return 0;
}
```

What should I do to get rid of this error? Thank you, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: `char alphabet[26] = {"A", "B", ..` -> `char alphabet[26] = {'A', 'B', ..` or simpler: `char alphabet[] = {"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");`. Be aware that with the last solution a NUL character comes after the 'Z' and the length of the array will be 27

Comment: `char alphabet[26] = {"A", "B"...` - You certainly wanted to use single quotes `''`, double quotes are *string-literals*

Comment: `"A"` is a string literal, consisting of `char[2] { 'A', '\0' }`.  What you probably want is a character value `'A'` instead.

Comment: Thank you! That helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating your alphabet out of string, instead of characters:

```
char alphabet[26] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};
```

Use:

```
char alphabet[26] = {'A', 'B', 'C', /* etc. */};
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 2):

The following code snippet generates similar errors:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{

    char alphabet[1] = {"A","B"};
    return 0;
}
```

1. ... main.cpp|6|error: too many initializers for 'char [1]'
2. ... main.cpp|6|error: initializer-string for array of chars is too long
   [-fpermissive]|
3. ... main.cpp|6|warning: unused variable 'alphabet'
   [-Wunused-variable]|

Build failed: 2 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 7 second(s)) ===|

---

Your code has the right number of locations for the alphabet, but you are storing two characters per location. In my code, I have only one location and I am trying to store two 'things'.

"A" means you have a string with characters 'A' followed by 0. You need to have two locations to store these. Now change the code to the following:

```
char alphabet[2][2] = {"A","B"};
```

If you do so then only the error (3) above remains. (This is for explanation only)

---

To initialize char, use single quotes. Have an appropriate number of locations to store the characters. I hope it helps.